# How to fix surface is not flat?

Tags: modeling

I try Blender first time. there a problem. Surface is not flat. Please view attached file for more details.

[image]

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuAcyL2kNiCPg7Z-0B-W61UGxhWk6Q?e=rk2ILF

Comment: First tell what you're trying to do. The image is unintelligible.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the bottom face and you'll see that you've got inner faces (a ring that goes all around), it messes up the faces normals, so delete them. Also flip the normals and delete the vertices that are almost overlapping.

[image]

Comment: Thank. I did it.